# AsyncTask getting paused on Android 8.1.0

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android application in which the application downloads **large number of files** from the server. The code is performing this download operation on background thread using **AsyncTask**.

During testing of the app on **Google Pixel Android 8.0 device**, I found that the download operation pauses if I keep the device idle for around **20-25 minutes**.

I have following questions:

1. Are there any settings in the code which can allow the code to continue the download operation?
2. Is this a feature of **Android Oreo** where the OS pauses the app from running for **battery optimization**?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Dont use an AsyncTask but a foreground service.

Answer (score 1):

Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces to improve battery life, when your app enters the [cached](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) state, with no active [components](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#Components), the system releases any wakelocks that the app holds.

For more information, see [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

You can use **Foreground Service** to performing the download operation.

The new [startForegroundService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) method starts a foreground service. The system allows apps to call `Context.startForegroundService()` even while the app is in the background. However, the app must call that service's `startForeground()` method within **five seconds** after the service is created otherwise the system stops the service and declares the app to be [ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The application's code is 2 years old and hence the code uses AsyncTask. Are there any settings I can do in gradle or manifest file which can fix this issue? I am fine even if its a workaround solution.

Comment: Try with setting your `compilesdkversion ` and `targetsdkversion` to **less than 26** in your gradle file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already set the **compilesdkversion** and **targetsdkversion** to 23 but the **buildToolsVersion** is set to "27.0.3". Do I need to change the **buildToolsVersion** also?